# MySQL prepared statement (two tables' data) and PHP while & for loop combination

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables in MySQL, using mysqli prepared statement.

MySQL Tables:

**Menu_table**

```
menuID (PK)    - menuName
    1             Menu 1
    2             Menu 2
    3             Menu 3
    4             Menu 4
```

**Submenu_table**

```
 submenuID(PK) -   submenuName   - menuID
    1               submenu 1     1
    2               submenu 2     1
    3               submenu 1     4
    4               submenu 2     4
```

My deadlock is to pass the correct value for submenu and menu while going through either While or For nested loops.

PHP Code (using WHILE loop and later using FOR loop and also combination):

```
<ul class="top-bar">
<?php
while($row = $stmt1->fetch()){
?>

            <li>
                <a href=""><span><?php echo($menuName);?></span></a>
                <?php 
                while($row = $stmt2->fetch()){
                    ?>
                    <ul class="sub"><li><?php echo($submenuName);?></li></ul>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </li>
        <?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

---

```
for($i=0; $i<$stmt1->num_rows;$i++){
    //write Menu Item
    //New loop through submenu
    //how to get index of Menu as reference point for submenu for loop
}
```

Expected result:

```
<ul class="top-bar">
    <li>
        <a href=""><span>Menu 1</span></a>
        <ul class="sub"><li>Submenu 1-1</li></ul>
        <ul class="sub"><li>Submenu 1-2</li></ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href=""><span>Menu 2</span></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href=""><span>Menu 3</span></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href=""><span>Menu 4</span></a>
        <ul class="sub"><li>Submenu 4-1</li></ul>
        <ul class="sub"><li>Submenu 4-2</li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing queries inside of loops. It sounds like what you're describing is a nested set, and there's lots of resources for representing these. If you use an ORM like Doctrine, you can use the Gedmo Nested Set extension to handle it. It's a very common problem, so there are a lot of solutions if you research trees and nested set.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, there is no query inside the loop. I just showed above (WHILE and FOR loop) the various things I've tried. I'll edit it right now.

Comment: Could you add some more of your PHP code? Right now there's simply not enough to go by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="top-bar">
<?php
while($row = $stmt1->fetch()){
?>

            <li>
                <a href=""><span><?php echo($menuName);?></span></a>
                <?php 
     $sql = "select * from submenu_table where menuID = ".$row['menuID'];
$stmt2->query($sql);
                while($sub_row = $stmt2->fetch()){
                    ?>
                    <ul class="sub"><li><?php echo($sub_row['submenuname']);?></li></ul>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </li>
        <?php
}
?>
</ul>
```